# Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect to phpmyadmin mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, xampp

I'm using the mysql module in my node.js code to connect to my xampp's mysql database like so:

```
let mysql = require('mysql');

let db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'quiz_database',
    user: 'root',
    password: ''
})

db.connect(function (error) {
    if (error) console.log(error);
    else console.log("MYSQL Connected...");
})

module.exports = db;
```

but when I run it, I get

```
  code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
  errno: 1045,
  sqlMessage: "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)",
  sqlState: '28000',
  fatal: true
```

I checked out some solutions online and it led me to changing my password in the shell using

> mysql -u root password

and I changed the password in the config.inc.php, but the problem still persists.
What do I do?

Comment: Note: phpMyAdmin is *not* a database, it is a front-end to your MySQL database. Your Node code connects directly to MySQL, it has no idea what phpMyAdmin is.

Comment: Tip: Create a user for your application, don't use "root".

Comment: I created a new user, and changed the details in my code, but i'm still getting the same error. It doesn't seem to identify my new user and still is referencing '''@''localhost'. How do i make it see the new user?

Comment: This should work if you're using the [`mysql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) dependency. Personally I think [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/) is better, it supports promises more fully, but that won't work either unless you resolve this initial issue.

Comment: Try making a single self-contained `.js` file you can use, then run it as a test. This export has a callback function call in it, meaning you can't be assured that `db` is fully initialized before using it.

Comment: I did as you said and everything worked fine. There seems to be an issue with the former code i have made. I will figure this out. Thank you very much